# SetInterval inside promise. Why this promise resolves immediately?

Tags: javascript, promise, setinterval

I am trying to understand how promises work

```
let promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    alert("started");
    let num = 0;
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        alert(`state ${num}`);
        num += 2;
        if (num > 4) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            alert("finished");
            resolve()
        }
    }, 1000)
});
promise.then(alert('resolved'))
```

By some reason i see immediately alerts `started`, `resolved`
and then, with interval 1sec `state 0`, `state 2`, `state 4` and `finished`.
Why  promise resolves instantly?
How to prevent promise from resolve until `resolve()` executed directly?

Comment: You are calling your callback instead of setting it as a callback...

Comment: Don't we have a clean dupe target for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.then` accepts a *function* as a parameter, not a plain statement or expression (unless said expression evaluates to a function). Use this instead:

```
promise.then(() => console.log('resolved'))
```

Demo:

```js
let promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("started");
    let num = 0;
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(`state ${num}`);
        num += 2;
        if (num > 4) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log("finished");
            resolve()
        }
    }, 1000)
});
promise.then(() => console.log('resolved'))
```